# Create table in Oracle as select from SQL Server - varchar size

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create table in Oracle 11g as select from a table in SQL Server 2012 via database link.

The table in SQL Server contains column: `hslakkis varchar(3)`

In Oracle it created the table with the same column but different size:
`hslakkis varchar2(9)`

This behavior causes me a lot of problems with the columns size in Oracle.
How can I prevent Oracle from increasing the column size?

Comment: What are the character sets on the two databases? That'll be the reason. (UTF antics)

Comment: The Oracle use AL32UTF8 character set while the Sql Server uses cp1255 character set.

Answer (score 5):

This is a feature that's controllable by a parameter. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12069/ch3.htm#GMSWN836):

> **Multi-byte Character Sets Ratio Suppression** This feature optionally suppresses the ratio expansion from SQL Server database to
>   Oracle database involving multi-byte character set. By default, Oracle
>   gateways assume the worst ratio to prevent data being truncated or
>   insufficient buffer size situation. However, if you have specific
>   knowledge of your SQL Server database and do not want the expansion to
>   occur, you can specify HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE parameter to
>   suppress the expansion.

Basically, Oracle is assuming that all of the data in the source table may take up 3 bytes per character, due to characterset conversion.

Comment: Yikes. Better be aware of that and apply the parameter!